# libprocesshider.so installed and added to /etc/ld.so.preload

Tags: security, backdoor

Today I received an alert from AlibabaCloud that `libprocesshider.so` is installed on my bastion server. They told me that it is a backdoor rootkit.

I researched for a bit and found out that `libprocesshider.so` is usually used to hide backdoor processes and it's a common practice to add the module to `/etc/ld.so.preload`, and it was indeed added on my server.

---

Questions:

- Can I trace all hidden processes that was ran with libprocesshider module?
- How can I track the damages it caused on my servers? I looked into `journalctl`, `/var/log/secure` and `history`, but couldn't find any trace of attack.
- The session that installed `libprocesshider.so` is still alive. I think the session was hijacked/stolen from a legit remote user. As the person is currently not connected to the bastion server. Should I kill the session ASAP, or can I trace some information from it?
- Is there a chance that `libprocesshider.so` was automatically installed by a non-malware
  application?

---

Please feel free to ask if you need more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I trace all hidden processes that was ran with libprocesshider module?

No. Why would that backdoor, of all things, keep a log?

> How can I track the damages it caused on my servers?

Not.

> I looked into journalctl, /var/log/secure and history, but couldn't find any trace of attack.

Well, when you go through the effort of hiding processes, why would you log your activities? Your server was probably used as part of a botnet to attack people to extort ransom, or to send spam emails, or to mine cryptocurrencies, or to host parts of highly illegal content. Or, it was to steal the data of you or your users.

> The session that installed libprocesshider.so is still alive. I think the session was hijacked/stolen from a legit remote user. As the person is currently not connected to the bastion server. Should I kill the session ASAP, or can I trace some information from it?

Err. That seems like a question with an obvious answer. Yes, kill the session, remove the user, tell all your other users that the data that they put on or through your server was probably compromised. Inform your clients; depending on where you are and what you do, you might also be legally obliged to tell the responsible official cybersecurity agencies what happened. Also:

**You should have powered off that server the moment you got to know of the exploitation.**

What good exactly are you doing by letting your server run if you can't know what your server is actually doing? For all we know you're currently making yourself criminally liable by allowing a detected criminal to operate from your infrastructure.

> Is there a chance that libprocesshider.so was automatically installed by a non-malware application?

no.

Comment: given the circumstance that the library was installed on my absence 2 weeks ago and today was my returning day, please excuse me for not jumping over to immediate protection mode. I thought it was too late for that and was trying to gain information out to explain 'why this happened'. Apparently, it was foolish.

Comment: Luckily it was installed on the bastion server which contains almost no private data. I'm only concerned about one thing. Is a hidden process still running on the background? If I have to assume that the hacker is no joke, rebooting won't do anything. What option do I have?

Comment: Should I decompile libprocesshider.so and search for a custom process file that the rootkit uses??

Comment: I said nothing about "write protected mode": I said you should have shut it down!

Comment: What good would any learning about that do? Or knowing *who exactly* was behind any of this? Just shut down that server, and provision a fresh, new VM with all security updates to replace that server. It's admirable you want to investigate this, but your organizational security and that of your users clearly takes priority. And:

Comment: "Luckily it was installed on the bastion server which contains almost no private data" That server is the one server through which users go to log in to other servers in your network, right? **any** credential that touched that server (not end-to-end encrypted) must be assumed to be compromised. This is not a "good case"; depending on what kind of things people do on your bastion server, it's damn near a worst-case scenario!

Comment: Unless you have means to be 100% sure that none of your users entered a password, API key on your bastion server, or put a private key there, be it on disk or in-memory, you have to presume that these credentials have been compromised. Installing a rootkit takes root privileges, and that means that all memory of all users was there for the attacker to read – and potentially to many attackers, some of which might have been smart enough *not* to leave a suspicious in-memory library there.

Comment: Ok I'll put my curiosity aside and prepare for the worst case scenario. Thank you for cutting off my bs.

Comment: @Lunartist hey, sorry for being so harsh :( Hope your day gets better!